# Remote interaction via VNC+Expect?

Tags: automation, expect, vnc, esxi

I've being doing a installation process in several machines in virtualbox and I'd like to try automated this process. I can do a expect script (see below), however I can't connect through ssh because this script will configure the network stuff after some other processes.

Where I work now, we use the vmware esxi and I am trying to discover if it's possible to automated the installation process that I said if I setup the vnc viewer in the guest machine. I can do the all process if I do it manually, but I'd like try to automated it. Although I think a expect script will be fine, I'm not connecting by ssh. Is it possible?? I started to think that maybe expect is not my answer here.

The processes is something like this:

1. Receives "Choose a option: ", sends "1\n"
2. Receives "Press any key", sends "\n"
3. Repeat step 2 more two times.
4. Receives "Do you agree (y/n)?", sends "y\n"
5. And so on.

The host as I said is a vmware esxi, the guest is similar to a linux and my machine is a fedora 20 (I'm saying this because I dont like the idea of install stuff on esxi).

Comment: Anyway some installation has to happen means, it will be some process which has to be initiated by terminal (hopefully). It is possible. Please post your code of trial along with the process interaction.

Comment: So, I'm asking if have some tool that allow me to interact with a vnc-viewer automatically in the same way that expect+ssh do. Do you know, @dinesh? This is my question here.

Comment: So,you mean opening a vnc-viewer and inside that you want to initiate the installation with `expect`?  Normally, expect can automate terminal interaction, not GUI, except [this](http://www.tcl.tk/man/expect5.31/expectk.1.html)

Comment: Actually, I was hoping to start a expect script that give spawn in the vncviewer and started to interact with it. I found information on the internet about people that start the vnc-viewer without password, but I need more interaction than that.